# Best way to make a trailing pixel?

Tags: xcode, swift, core-graphics, particles

So in swift, for iOS devices (though cross platform would be cool if I can still code in Xcode) I am trying to do something rather simple.

All I want to do is have little particles moving around on the screen leaving trails.  Unfortunately I cant use traditional particle systems because I need to program their movement.

Anyway I was figuring that if I could keep all the pixels in a large array and just changing them as I need to.  That way I can set pixels based on the particle, and just fade them away each frame, thus giving the illusion of a trail.

What would be a good way to do this? I have been looking at quarts, core graphics, and opengles however I cant find a single tutorial that tells me how to draw a single pixel... Just ones that tell how to draw lines and other stuff.  I just need to be able to draw the screen pixel by pixel (unless you have a better idea)

1. What framework should I use
2. How do I draw a single pixel in it given an x,y screen coordinate (or link a tutorial).

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreImage with `CIImageAccumulator` can help you do this. In my [FurrySketch](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/furrysketch-hirsute-drawing-with-apple.html) project, I do something very similar. In a nutshell:

1. Begin a UI Graphics Context: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)`
2. Use functions such as `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to draw to the context
3. Create a `CIImage` of the drawing: `let drawnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`
4. Use a `CISourceOverCompositing` to composite that new image over the previous one in the accumulator and write the composite image back to the accumulator:

   `compositeFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: drawnImage),
       forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
   compositeFilter.setValue(imageAccumulator.image(),
       forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
   imageAccumulator.setImage(compositeFilter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage)`
5. Display the new composite in the UI: `imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: imageAccumulator.image())`

By also adding a blur to that image, you can get your particles to fade out too, as I've done [here](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/forcesketch-3d-touch-drawing-app-using.html).

Comment: So I was looking at that code.  Unfortunately I cant use composite filters as I am trying to target iOS 8.0+.  Is their an other option?